# How to make a modal inside another one and the last one to disappear when another one is open in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
        $(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 
    

});
```

```css
.popup {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(193, 49, 49, 0.55);
    z-index: 99;
}
.popup-1{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:green;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-1" data-popup="popup-2">
  <button type="button"><a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Regjistrohu</a></button>
</div>
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
  <button type="button"><a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#">login</a></button>
</div>
<button type="button"><a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#">add</a></button>
```

Hello I'm  doing  a login and register  form like a modal in Jquery  when i click to login inside register modal  it work but when I try to register in login modal i doesn't work  also i want to disappear one off them when another one is active. so far her is my code:  http://codepen.io/xhepigerta/pen/vGRdvb
Can someone help me please?   thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ do u see now

Comment: better here http://codepen.io/xhepigerta/pen/vGRdvb

Comment: I think, you're using custom popup modals, not bootstrap modals. So, in this case, you can always use the `fadeIn/fadeOut` callbacks to `show/hide` the relevant modal. e.g. `$("#registermodal").fadeIn( 500, function(){ $("#loginmodal").fadeOut(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('[data-popup]').not($('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]')).fadeOut();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/redJgG